# I want to update one table data based on the join condition with another table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I tried to update a column in one table from another table using join condition. I tried all possible ways and its showing SQL command not properly ended.I am trying t his in sql server.

```
update a 
   set a.col4=b.col4 
from dummy_jd a 
  join --select * from dummy_jd a, 
     (select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,sum(reported_amount) reported_amount 
      from dummy_jd_2 
      where col5=3843 
      and col3='abc' 
      and col1=4 
      and col2=3002 
      group by col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
  ) b on (a.col2=b.col5 and a.col4=b.col3) 
where a.col1=9;
```

This is which i tried

Comment: update a  set a.col4=b.col4 from  dummy_jd a  join 
--select * from dummy_jd a,
(select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,sum(reported_amount) reported_amount
 from dummy_jd_2 where col5=3843
and col3='abc'
and col1=4
and col2=3002
group by col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)b on
 (a.col2=b.col5
and a.col4=b.col3)
where a.col1=9;
This is which i tried....

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server) ?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Dear Tim, I dont know much about it this may be sql server or oracle

Comment: Well you need to find this out, because otherwise no one on this site will be able to help you.

Comment: Can you help me how can i find

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
update a set a.col4=b.col4 from dummy_jd a
join 
(select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,sum(reported_amount) reported_amount 
from dummy_jd_2 where col5=3843 and col3='abc' and col1=4 and col2=3002 
group by col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
)b on a.col2=b.col5 and a.col4=b.col3
where a.col1=9
```

Comment: thanks... I tried exactly same but still still its throwing "sql command not properly ended error"

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thanks to everyone i achieved it by using for loopand joins  below is the query i used
    for i in (select * from dummy_jd1)
    loop 
    update dummy_jd a set a.col4 = (select distinct col4 from dummy_jd_2  b
                     where /*(jnl_ref_no, bill_ref_no) in (select 
                       jnl_ref_no,bill_ref_no from dummy_jd1) and*/
                        a.col2 = b.col5
                       and a.col4 = b.col3
                       and b.col5 = i.col2
                       and b.col3 = i.col3
                       and id_type = 4
                          --and id_value in(3002,3019)
                       and reported_amount <> 0
                     group by col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)


  where a.id_type = 9
  and a.col2=i.col2
  and a.col4=i.col3;
```